# Sync folder outside SkyDrive on OS X

Tags: macos, onedrive

After the recent 25 GB update, I wanted to sync my pictures with SkyDrive as I finally have enough space *(My almost 10 GB Dropbox is full with other data and I need more than 10 GB for my pictures alone)*.

Anyway, the symlink (`ln -s`) option is not really working as it just creates an alias inside the skydrive which is not even synchronised. Is there any other option or do I have to live with moving the pictures folder into SkyDrive (which I wouldn't really want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Skydrive for Mac seems to ignore symlinked directories (which is strange, because [on Windows it does follow junctions](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/04/24/how-to-add-external-folders-to-skydrive/)).

You can use `rsync` to hardlink your pictures (file-by-file) into the Skydrive folder. This won't use any disk space (almost), and is completely safe. And Skydrive does sync hardlinked files.

[This question describes hardlinking with rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/209888/how-can-i-use-rsync-to-duplicate-a-directory-tree-creating-hardlinks-to-files).